# Matlab installantion error on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: matlab

each time i try to install matlab using this command

```
muhammad@muhammad-Inspiron-N5050:~/Applications/matlab/forubuntu$ ./install
```

it displays and close the installation box
for the command
 ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so command. – ls: 
cannot access command.: No such file or directory ls: cannot access –: No such file or directory -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10424 مارچ 27 23:05 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so

```
Preparing installation files ...
->  DVD                 = /home/muhammad/Applications/matlab/forubuntu
->  ARCH                = glnxa64
->  DISPLAY             = :0
->  TESTONLY            = 0
->  JRE_LOC             = /tmp/mathworks_8893/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre
->  LD_LIBRARY_PATH     = /tmp/mathworks_8893/bin/glnxa64

Command to run:
/tmp/mathworks_8893/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m  -splash:"/home/muhammad/Applications/matlab/forubuntu/java/splash.png" -Djava.ext.dirs=/tmp/mathworks_8893/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/ext:/tmp/mathworks_8893/java/jar:/tmp/mathworks_8893/java/jar/ja_JP/:/tmp/mathworks_8893/java/jar/zh_CN/:/tmp/mathworks_8893/java/jarext:/tmp/mathworks_8893/java/jarext/axis2/:/tmp/mathworks_8893/java/jarext/guice/:/tmp/mathworks_8893/java/jarext/webservices/ com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/home/muhammad/Applications/matlab/forubuntu" -tmpdir "/tmp/mathworks_8893" 

Installing ...
/tmp/mathworks_8893/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: file too short
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardModule.provideDisplayProperties(WizardModule.java:68)
  while locating com.mathworks.instutil.DisplayProperties
  at com.mathworks.wizard.ui.components.ComponentsModule.providePaintStrategy(ComponentsModule.java:76)
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.components.PaintStrategy
    for parameter 4 at com.mathworks.wizard.ui.components.SwingComponentFactoryImpl.<init>(SwingComponentFactoryImpl.java:111)
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.components.SwingComponentFactoryImpl
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.components.SwingComponentFactory
    for parameter 1 at com.mathworks.wizard.ui.WizardUIImpl.<init>(WizardUIImpl.java:62)
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.WizardUIImpl
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.WizardUI annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=BaseWizardUI)
  at com.mathworks.wizard.ui.UIModule.provideWizardUI(UIModule.java:50)
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.WizardUI
    for parameter 0 at com.mathworks.wizard.ExceptionHandlerImpl.<init>(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:22)
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ExceptionHandlerImpl
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ExceptionHandler

1 error
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:767)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:793)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardLauncher.startWizard(WizardLauncher.java:156)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardLauncher.start(WizardLauncher.java:71)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.AbstractLauncher.launch(AbstractLauncher.java:27)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.AbstractLauncher.launchStandalone(AbstractLauncher.java:18)
    at com.mathworks.professionalinstaller.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:804)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:101)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: com.mathworks.instutil.JNIException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/mathworks_8893/bin/glnxa64/libinstutil.so: /tmp/mathworks_8893/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: file too short
    at com.mathworks.instutil.NativeUtility.loadNativeLibrary(NativeUtility.java:39)
    at com.mathworks.instutil.NativeUtility.<init>(NativeUtility.java:24)
    at com.mathworks.instutil.DisplayPropertiesImpl.<init>(DisplayPropertiesImpl.java:10)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardModule.provideDisplayProperties(WizardModule.java:75)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/mathworks_8893/bin/glnxa64/libinstutil.so: /tmp/mathworks_8893/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: file too short
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.instutil.NativeUtility.loadNativeLibrary(NativeUtility.java:37)
```

Comment: post the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so` command.

Comment: muhammad@muhammad-Inspiron-N5050:~/Applications/matlab/forubuntu$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so command. –  
ls: cannot access command.: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access –: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10424 مارچ  27 23:05 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so

Comment: is that file present or not?

Comment: @AvinashRaj  ls: cannot access command.: No such file or directory ls: cannot access –: No such file or directory -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10424 مارچ 27 23:05 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so

Comment: please post the above comment in your question.

Comment: i don't know how to check that file  and if i write ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so     it gives -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10424 مارچ  27 23:05 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so   @AvinashRaj

Comment: try to reinstall `glib-networking:amd64` package by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall glib-networking:amd64`

Comment: i installed ubuntu few days ago so i don't know much about                               few days ago i tried to install xilinx ise webpack it gives no such file and directory using command ls it shows file is present but when i run it gives no file or directory
autorun.inf  CodeSourcery  Crack  DocNav  idata  labtools            Microsoft.VC90.MFC  
bin          common        data   edk     ise    Microsoft.VC90.CRT  msg                 sdk        vivado  webpack     xsetup.exe
muhammad@muhammad-Inspiron-N5050:~/XilinxISE/xilinxise142w$ ./xsetup
bash: ./xsetup: No such file or directory

Comment: @AvinashRaj i used your command after the package is reinstalled i run the setup but it gives same error.

Comment: the problem is fixed using the link below                           http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/56822-installation-probelms-r2012b-on-ubuntu-12-10-quantal     @AvinashRaj thanks for your help can you help me now with xilinx ise webpack installation

Comment: please post it as an answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it does not allow me to post you can post the answer i will remove it the comment

Comment: @AvinashRaj now after 80 percent installation it gives error                                                                The following error was detected while installing sl3d_glnxa64:  archive is not a ZIP archive  Would you like to retry installing sl3d_glnxa64? If you press No, the installer will exit without completing the installation. More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_root.log

Comment: see `/tmp/mathworks_root.log` file.

Comment: @AvinashRaj  what is meant?

Comment: post the output of `cat /tmp/mathworks_root.log` command in pastebin.

Comment: @AvinashRaj                                                   ~$ at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:181)
 at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:158)bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:119)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:119)
at com.mathworks.install.archive.zip.commonscompress.CopyInputStreamToTempZipFileExtractor.extract(CopyInputStreamToTempZipFileExtractor.java:43)

Comment: please post that on pastebin.

Comment: @AvinashRaj  it gives many lines like this

Comment: @AvinashRaj   i pasted it link is http://pastebin.com/27i4wawc

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in the [matlab/install/dir]/bin/glnxa64/ a symbolic link is converted into a text file and doesn't behave as a link anymore. It must be replaced by a new one.

```
cd bin/glnxa64
rm libstdc++.so.6
ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.13 libstdc++.so.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand user276568 answer, if you're installing from a CDROM, the file system is write only.

You can workaround this with directory binds:

```
cp -dR [cdrom path]/bin/glnxa64/ /tmp
cd /tmp/glnxa64
rm libstdc++.so.6
ln -s libstdc++.so.6.* libstdc++.so.6
sudo mount -o bind /tmp/glnxa64/ [cdrom path]/bin/glnxa64/
```

You can also copy the CDROM content to a writeable filesystem.